# What if someone else answer (almost same as mine) was posted later than mine and was Accepted!

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I answered this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32776314/4946310) on **2015-09-25** and my timing of my last edit **07:16:33Z**. [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32776775/4946310) was posted by someone at **2015-09-25 07:16:46Z**, obviously later than mine edit. And this answer was exactly same as [mine answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32776662/4946310). The author of the question accepted his answer as the best answer. I don't know why, although it was totally same. I don't know what to do? Should I report this issue to someone? Or just ignore this injustice?

Comment: Injustice, perhaps! Enough that you should get worked up about? Probably not.

Comment: Ignore it. There is a bazillion valid reasons why the OP may have favoured the other guy's answer over yours, even though yours may have been equal or better in quality. It happens.

Comment: **Almost** the same isn't **exactly** the same. The questioner may have just preferred the phrasing in the accepted answer to yours.

Comment: @IKavanagh I doubt it too..

Comment: it isn't exactly the same, just there is a generic function to setAttributes, but the OP didn't asked about creating a generic functin for this..

Comment: Maybe your first revision was seen by the OP and that might not have helped, being the first to answer might be beneficial in some cases but not in all, as demonstrated here.

Comment: @IKavanagh the other guy might have phrased better in the beginning but in the code I've given a lot detail of each statement.. and a commented out code is much more preferable!

Comment: A question with -5 votes and the only answer of it with +5 votes.. how can this be?? A bad question with a good answer.. ohh I just got an upvoter..

Comment: @rene the OP wasn't online at that time, I think. He accepted the answer very late 20 mins later.. so he must have seen the final version of my answer

Comment: On meta voting is different. In general whining about injustice is greeted with downvotes.

Comment: @rene got that, this was my first post on meta! well I've learnt from my mistake..

Comment: -6 is not so bad. I still win with my lowest scoring answer on meta ;)

Comment: Too bad... bear with it... Sometimes that happen. I encounter a couple of such cases too. But we cannot force anyone to accept anybody's answer.

Answer (score 11):

You can't know for sure which answer the OP tried/tested first. Maybe he like that user's almost 20k rep and decided to try his first purposely, or maybe that answer was just what appeared first when he loaded the page again..

We don't know.

The questioner has every right to use his accept vote the way he wants. So there is nothing you or moderator could do about it.

So yes, just ignore it and move on.

Comment: okay, I gotta move on!!